# display first element of list of string in visualforce

Tags: visualforce

i need to display text in visualforce page, what i have access to is a List. i need to display first element of this list as text on page.

```
List<String> listOfStrings;

<h4>{!what expression to use listOfStrings}</h4>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass `0` at index of list as:

```
public List<String> listOfStrings {get;set;}
<h4>{! IF(listOfStrings.size > 0, listOfStrings[0], '') }</h4>
```

Comment: i cannot save page with this syntax : {!listOfStrings[0]}. Seems syntax is not valid.

Comment: Did you define get; set; ? @Walker

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular "array" notation to show the first element. Be sure to check to make sure the list is neither null nor empty before trying to access an array element.

```
{!listOfStrings[0]}
```

Alternatively, you can use a repeat element:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!listOfStrings}" var="varString" rows="1">{!varString}</apex:repeat>
```

Obviously, this is a bit more verbose, but works all the same.

Finally, you can also simply use a getter method in Apex Code:

```
public String getFirstString() {
    return listOfStrings != null && listOfStrings.size() > 0? listOfStrings[0]: null;
}
```

Which is then used as:

```
{!firstString}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Walker Here I have tried to create a VF page and a Controller as explained by **sfdcfox** and **Ashwani** above. Hope this helps.

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" controller="ListString">
    <h4>what expression to use {!listOfStrings[0]}</h4><br/>
    <h4>what expression to use <apex:repeat value="{!listOfStrings}" var="varString" rows="1">{!varString}</apex:repeat></h4><br/>
    <h4>what expression to use {!firstString}</h4><br/>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class ListString {
    public List<String> listOfStrings {get;set;}
    public ListString() {
        listOfStrings = new List<String>();
        listOfStrings.add('Hello');
        listOfStrings.add('World');
    }
    public String firstString {
        get {
            return listOfStrings != null && listOfStrings.size() > 0? listOfStrings[0]: null;
        }
        set;
    }   
}
```