# Visualforce page help

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, wrapper-class

We have created one visualforcepage on order object which is working as expected,but i want to show the message field from different object (FusionOrder)  field Message on the same VF page, here is the "Fusion Order object" is child of "order" Object.

Can any one please help us to this?

Answer (score 0):

Fusion_Order_File is a child of Order. How do you know which record to be picked for the message field ?

If you are sure that there's going to be only one child record, you can add a subquery on the Order object SOQL

Something like this should work on your VF Page:

[how to display parent and child records in visualforce page with seperate pageblocktables using classes?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24235/how-to-display-parent-and-child-records-in-visualforce-page-with-seperate-pagebl)

[display first element of list of string in visualforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/91794/display-first-element-of-list-of-string-in-visualforce)

Another approach would be to query all the Fusion_Order_File records separately and create a Map of Key=OrderId and Value=Fusion_Order_File.Message and use that in your current table:

e.g.

```
<apex:column >
<apex:facet name="header">Message</apex:facet>
<apex:outputText value="{!orderMsgMap[qo.id]}" />
</apex:column>
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_maps_lists.htm